# How to add attribute to model from join request (Yii1)?

Tags: php, yii

My code is:

```
$criteria = new MyCDbCriteria;                
$criteria->select = 't.id, acc.server_account, t.registration_date, lac.login, t.summ, t.input, t.output, t.lot, t.options_sum, t.profit';
$criteria->join = 'join `accounts` acc on (t.account_id = acc.id) join `users` u on (acc.user_id = u.id) join `leads_and_clients` lac on (u.login = lac.login)';
$records = PartnersReport::model()->findAll($criteria);
foreach ($records as $record) {
    foreach ($record->attributes as $key => $val) {
        $return['values'][$record->id][$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

The problem: there is no "joined" attributes like `server_account` in `$record->attributes`. How to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a property PartnersReport::server_account and use it as alias in SELECT:

$criteria->select = 't.id, acc.server_account AS server_account, t.registration_date, lac.login, t.summ, t.input, t.output, t.lot, t.options_sum, t.profit';

Comment: How to add a property `PartnersReport::server_account`? Actually I don't understand where I can do this. If inside model, then where exactly?

Comment: class Mymodel extends Cactiverecord {
      public $server_account;
}